# Visual Studio 2015 - ..package did not load correctly

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've just installed vs2015 on a win10 VM and get a series of package did not load correctly errors. VisualBasicPackage, FileIndicatorPackage and so on.

I found a previous question from VS2010 that sounds very similar, but no solution was provided.

All projects have the same errors. I've installed VS2013 alongside it and it works perfectly, I also have my previous dev VM running 2013 on win 8.1 for the last 2 years with no issues, so it appears to be VS2015 specific.

Any help with this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it has something to do with the parallel install of VS2013.

I did a similar setup a few hours ago (Win10 VM vanilla with only VS2015CE) and those problems didn't occur.

Update: Seems that there are some people with similar issues. Maybe this link may help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/858ed562-f563-4b64-838d-4b6870986e4b/universal-apps-windows-10-error?forum=visualstudiogeneral